# Shell script command substitution with multiple commands

Tags: shell

I'm developing a shell script where I have the variable RUN as a result of a command substitution.

Something like this:

```
RUN="$(kubectl logs ${POD_LISTENER} | grep ${FROM_DATE})"
OUTPUT=$(eval $RUN)
```

Problem is with the grep portion.

The pattern I'm searching with grep is a date, so I need to add single quote around the variable `${FROM_DATE}` to match exactly what I need.

From the terminal, I run the command below and get the result I need

```
kubectl logs cortex-listener-prod-6b8884d45b-mlmzz | grep '2018-08-11'
```

And it work well, but I can't make it run from the script.

Comment: can you post how you are assigning value to `FROM_DATE`

Comment: the variable FROM_DATE is assigned like this: FROM_DATE=`date -v-"$1d" +%Y-%m-%d`   where the number of days is passed as a script parameter

Comment: try RUN=$(kubectl logs ${POD_LISTENER} | grep "${FROM_DATE}")

Answer (score 0):

I don't see, why you need to quote your FROM_DATE, because this string contains only digits and hyphens, and neither one is treated as a filename character in a POSIX shell. However, your outer double quotes don't make sense. Just use

```
RUN=$(kubectl logs $POD_LISTENER | grep $FROM_DATE)
```